# routes pointing to the same location nginx

Tags: angular, laravel, nginx

in my application i have two routes

1. /login route managed by angular to show the actual login page
2. /login used by laravel to authenticate users on the back-end

when in development the two applications run on two different ports so angular will serve the login page at `mystie.com/login:4200`

and laravel will send the data to `mystic.com/login:8000` to authenticate users
so there is no problem here.

In production thou i have an nginx server with this configuration

```
server {
    include mime.types;
    root /var/www/html/myForum/forum-frontend/dist/forum-frontend;
    index index.html;

    server_name myforum.dev www.myforum.dev;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location ~/(api|sanctum|login) {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
```

the problem with this configuration is that when navigating to mystie.com/login nginx will forward the information to laravel and will not show the actual login page.

if i remove login from the second location it `mystic/login` will be handled by angular and the server will not forward the login information to laravel

I know is a bit tricky but i can't find a solution to manage those responsibilities

Answer (score 0):

Add a `listen 8000;` directive to your Laravel's `server` block

Comment: i have only one server block, should i separate them?

Comment: yes, try this. One for your Angular app on 80 port, and one for backend on 8000 port